# nmap EPERM error with a MAP_FIXED flag enabled

Tags: linux, mmap

I have a simple mmap program that behaves differently in two linux machines:

> cat a.c

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <errno.h>


   #include <sys/mman.h>
   #include <err.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <unistd.h>

   int
   main(void)
   {
           int fd = -1;
           char *A, *zero;

           if ((fd = open("./a.out", O_RDONLY, 0)) == -1)
                   exit(1);

           A = mmap(NULL, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, fd, 0);

           if (A == MAP_FAILED)
              printf("error %d, errno=%d\n", A, errno);
           else
               printf("OK %d\n", A);
           return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

In one machine `mmap` returns with success but the other machine it prints error (errno is 1).

Relevant differences in `strace` results are:

Good one:

```
(2.6.9-78.ELsmp #1 SMP Wed Jul 9 15:46:26 EDT 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
open("./a.out", O_RDONLY)               = 3
mmap(NULL, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0
```

Failed one:

```
( 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5 #1 SMP Fri Oct 29 14:21:16 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
open("./a.out", O_RDONLY)               = 3
mmap(NULL, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

In the failed one, if I get rid of MAP_FIXED flag, mmap succeeds. Seems that the failed process doesn't have memory space [0, 65535] available for mapping.

I don't know where to look into for this problem? What could be the cause for the different behavior and failure? Or more specificailly, if my guess that the failure is due to unavailable [0,65535], what could be the cause that one machine has it available while the other one doesn't?

Comment: Does it work on the second system if you put SELinux into permissive mode (`setenforce 0`, with `setenforce 1` to change it back after)?

Comment: setenforce doesn't help: ~/exp/>setenforce 0
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
~/exp/>a.out
error -1, errno=1
~/exp/>setenforce 1
setenforce: SELinux is disabled
~/exp/>a.out
error -1, errno=1

Comment: Output of `sysctl vm.mmap_min_addr` in both systems?

Comment: the bad one: vm.mmap_min_addr = 4096, it works when I set it to 0. :) (the good one: error: 'vm.mmap_min_addr' is an unknown key).

Answer (score 2):

You have specified `MAP_FIXED` with an address of zero. By default on recent versions of Linux, and can be configured on some earlier versions, mapping at low virtual address is prohibited in order to prevent exploitation of kernel null pointer dereference bugs.

Answer (score 0):

mmap MAP_FIXED according the the man page `[Doesn't] interpret addr as a hint: place the mapping at exactly that address.`. [addr]ess is NULL in your example (first mmap argument).

NULL is mapped to a zero page pretty much always so EPERM is probably a expected response.

Its previous working case is probably a bug (was A mapped to a zero page containing the contents of the file?)